# Как сделать поиск и выделение по шаблону OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, распознавание-символов

Не могу понять, что не так? Ищу картинку в картинке, а выделения происходят не там, где нужно Опробовал все методы поиска

[image: Фрагмент который ищу]

[image: фото где ищу]

[image: результат]

Код:

```
import cv2
method = cv2.TM_CCOEFF
small_image = cv2.imread('shab4.png') # что ищу
large_image = cv2.imread('output.png') # где ищу
result = cv2.matchTemplate(small_image, large_image, method)
mn,_,mnLoc,_ = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
MPx,MPy = mnLoc
trows,tcols = small_image.shape[:2]
cv2.rectangle(large_image, (MPx,MPy),(MPx+tcols,MPy+trows),(0,0,255),5)
res = cv2.resize(large_image, dsize=(2500,2500))
cv2.namedWindow("Resized", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("Resized", res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Почему-то код может находить картинку в картинке, а вот текст нет.

Answer (score 0):

cv2.matchTemplate возвращает непредсказуемые результаты, которые чаще всего совпадают с требуемым результатом, что вводит пользователя в заблуждение о надёжности данной функции. То есть полагаться на эту функцию нельзя, никогда. Она может даже найти изобаржение, где его нет и быть не может (во всех режимах поиска).
Здесь нужен иной подход: создавать искомое изображение из текста, при помощи pillow сравнивать пиксели (если нет прозрачности, то результаты довольно точны). Иными словами самостоятельно писать функцию поиска, в нете нет реализации оной.